# Cant add like box to blogger

Tags: blogger, facebook-social-plugins

I have been trying to add a like box onto my blog. I went into the facebook developers site and got the url code. WHen I go to add a gadget in the template it is telling me the gadget is broken. AM I missing something? here is the code I am putting in

http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsunflowerfluff&width=292&height=590&show_faces=true&colorscheme=light&stream=true&border_color&header=true

Answer (score 1):

When you press the **Get Code** button, it will give you four options i.e HTML5, XFBML, IFrame and URL.

Copy the **IFRAME** Code.

Go to blogger, **Add Gadget** and paste the whole code.